# Rails, Subdomain based cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a rails application which is Subdomain based. It also contains REST API which can be publicly accessed to our clients. I have an another client application through which I am accessing the REST API of the main app.

When I am accessing both the apps on the same browser and logged in the main app, I am not able to access the REST API of different Subdomain in client app as cookie get stored according to the domain accessed.

Is there any way to differentiate the cookies based on Subdomain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should set cookie's domain as **.yourdomain.com** so that your cookies are set for main domain and for all subdomains.

Rails 3 on config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_my_key', :domain => ".yourdomain.com"
```

Rails 2.3+ on config/environment.rb:

```
config.action_controller.session = { :key => '_my_key', :domain => '.yourdomain.com' }
```

Comment: Its funny you should say that because we have exactly the settings you recommend, yet for some reason occasionally the session cookie will get set to "example.com" instead of ".example.com". I am trying to debug why this happens as I've looked through the code for likely suspects and found none. Since we already have the settings you suggest, what next?